# Create MSTeams Personal chat with customized name

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are trying the following payload using MSTeams Bot access Token to create the Personel chat Room with the provided topicName.

Request : POST /v3/conversations

```
{
    
    "bot": {
            "id": "28:XXXXXXXX-a2Xe-460b-8793-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "XXXXXXXX"
        },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "29:18KXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "Jane"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "News",
    "tenantId": "XXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-829b-5131e9a77XXX"
}
```

In response we got the resource id and we can post Bot message using that Id. But that message is always shown in the Personal Chat \room and it is not creating c chat with the topicName.

Is there any other permissions we need to add ?

Comment: To create a chat with customized name you should have minimum 3 participants[Including you]. In the above request only one user is there, that is why it becomes one-one personal chat between you and Jane.  Also could you please share the sample you are following to execute the above request.

Comment: We referred the _Conversation parameters_ object in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#conversationparameters-object and created the payload.

Comment: Please create the chat with minimum 3 participants[Including you] to get a chat with customized name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a chat with customized name you should have minimum 3 participants[Including you]. In the above request only one user is there, that is why it becomes one-one personal chat between you and Jane.